# How do I continuously check variables that are held by a webserver from Android device?

Tags: android, labview

I recently set up a web service using LABVIEW which exhibits a bunch of shared variables which can be changed via buttons in the LABVIEW program itself.

Apart from this I would also like to control the shared variables via my Android phone. 
Actually, this works pretty well and I can also see the LABVIEW button's state change when I click the Android buttons within my app.

My question is now: Up to now the LABVIEW buttons' state is only updated but the other way round doesn't hold true. How can I make the Android buttons' state change when using the LABVIEW buttons?
Do I have to employ IntentServices or do I have to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly how LABVIEW works but basically you are providing some server-client communication functionality. So there is no magic way of updating your android's application state based on changes happening on the server side. basically you will have to follow **polling** or **pushing** approach.
Either your application can ask the server periodically (poll), or your server has to notify the client when the changes occur (push). The first approach is simple but will eventually drain your battery quicker, meanwhile pushing messages from server to client is more elegant but requires greater efforts.

*How can I make the Android buttons' state change when using the LABVIEW buttons?*

Using poll or push approach.

*Do I have to employ IntentServices?*

**You dont have to**. But eventually your notification mechanism will reside on a service. it might happen that IntenService is a good solution but depends on your requirements.

*Do I have to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)?*

**You dont have to**. There are other solutions as well such as establishing yourself a socket level communication.But GCM might be quicker for your case.